# Efficiency of loading from one table vs loading from two tables with the same structure, and Unioning the results. (no indexes, MSSQL)

Tags: sql-server, select, database-performance, union-all

Is it more efficient to put all data of a certain type into a single table for loading, or is it better to have it in two tables and union the results?
This is to optimize performance for the software that is loading the data.

Comment: I'm referencing this answer in a discussion with a work colleague.  By pasting it here, I add knowledge to mankind and it's in the cloud so I can always reference the result in future without having to remember where I stored it.  For this reason, the option to answer your own question is provided as a checkbox by stack overflow, so you can ask and answer at once.  But if you have experience with this issue, you should add to the answers.

Comment: So is that answer from somewhere else? If so, you should be linking to the answer/article and citing; not posting it as your own. :)

Comment: No, I calculated these results myself immediately before posting the question and the answer together.

Comment: @Markus SO isn't a blogging service and the question is so vague that it can't be answered. *It depends* on the query itself, indexing and constraints on the tables. `Return all` queries are meaningless as benchmarks too. They only measure the disk's performance the *first* time a query is executed.

Comment: Logically, all data of the same "type" ought to be co-located, so a single table approach would be used. If there are performance issues to be addressed, these would usually be accomplished using *physical* tools, such as indexes or partitioning. This leaves the *logical* data structure intact. Which tools to use would be based on *all* operations/queries in which the data is involved though, not just a single "load all of the data" query.

Comment: I updated the question to indicate the table structures would be identical and there are no indexes.  This code is for the first time the query is run, however the code can be used to do other comparisons.  I don't think the performance of union selecting from A and B would eventually become faster or slower than selecting from AB.  Do you?

Comment: Either you're using an inappropriate measure to perform your benchmarking or you've picked the wrong tool for your job. If the only thing you care about is one-off load performance, pick a flat file over a relational database system.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, the scenario is that data comes in from 2 sources, and whether each source be put into the same table or different tables, specifically for the fastest average reading and writing?  This question is for a simple case involving no indexes.  I'll put another page for the case with indexes.

Comment: You have a scenario in mind. Great. There are *no details* of that scenario in your question, and it's still far from clear why a relational database system is *in any way* a necessary part of dealing with that scenario.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, the purpose of these tests is a real world application, but the question is relevant even if it wasn't.  You don't need to guess about the real world application to answer the question.

Comment: Yes, but at the moment, from all we have in the question, my answer would still be "neither, use flat file(s) and ignore SQL Server entirely". There's nothing here that *motivates* us to use SQL Server at all for this and it still feels like we've picked the *wrong tool* for this poorly defined problem.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, sql-server was in the tags, but I put it in the question also now.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that it makes negligible difference to the loading software in terms of the work done by SQL server, I did the following tests.
The first test inserts 100k rows into each of 2 tables, and loads the data from the two tables.
The second test inserts 200k rows into 1 table, and loads it.
Conclusion?
The time taken to save 100k rows to two tables is the same as it is to save 200k rows to one table. (79 seconds) 
The time taken to select all 200k rows of data split over two tables is the same as the time taken to select 200k rows of data from a single table. (10 seconds for 10 selects).

Here is the code:

Insert to two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE GpsDataA ( GpsDataID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), X float, Y float );

 DECLARE @i int = 0;
 WHILE (@i < 100000) 
 BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO GpsDataA ( X, Y ) VALUES (1, 2);
   SET @i = @i + 1;
 END

 CREATE TABLE GpsDataB ( GpsDataID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), X float, Y float );

 DECLARE @i2 int = 0;
 WHILE (@i2 < 100000) 
 BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO GpsDataB ( X, Y ) VALUES (1, 2);
   SET @i2 = @i2 + 1;
 END
  -- 1m19s  to insert to both tables
```

Inserting 200k rows to a single table:

```
 CREATE TABLE GpsDataAB ( GpsDataID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), X float, Y float );

 DECLARE @i int = 0;
 WHILE (@i < 200000) 
 BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO GpsDataAB ( X, Y ) VALUES (1, 2);
   SET @i = @i + 1;
 END
 -- 1m19s  to insert to one table
```

Selecting 10 times from the two tables:

```
DECLARE @i int = 0;
 WHILE (@i < 10) 
 BEGIN 
   SELECT * 
    FROM GpsDataA 
   UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM GpsDataB
  SET @i = @i + 1;
 END
```

-- 10s to run above code

Selecting 200k rows from a single table:

```
DECLARE @i int = 0;
 WHILE (@i < 10) 
 BEGIN 
   SELECT * 
    FROM GpsDataAB
  SET @i = @i + 1;
 END
```

-- 10s to run above code

Comment: If you were to change your `insert` statements to a more efficient set based solution (Such as one of [these](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/)) to bring down the overall processing times, do you see much difference?

Comment: Measuring time is meaningless as a way to benchmark anything. SQL Server caches results so subsequent calls only load the already cached data. A query that simply loads everything doesn't excercise anything either apart from the IO performance of the disk.

Comment: Surely if I create a new table for the experiment, it can't cache the results?  Unless it stored the names of previous tables and then checked the list of old dropped tables to see in the cache if the cached results of the nonexistent tables is still there, on the assumption that if they have the same name as a name of a table in the dropped table list, they may contain useful results?  Anyway, I ran the test only once.